# Accessing the fill color of a path in a resource dictionary, directly in the XAML file

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my XAML, I have a button like this:

```
<Button Name="btnName" Width="194" TabIndex="3514" Click="btnName_Click" Margin="5,10,0,10"  >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ContentControl Width="16" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="{StaticResource iconFolderOpen}" />
                        <Label>Click Me</Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
```

In my resource dictionary, I have a style defined to draw out the icon:

```
<Viewbox x:Key="iconFolderOpen" x:Shared="False" Stretch="Uniform">
        <Path Fill="#ff2d66b0" Data="F1 M 15.736,7.579 L 12.875,10.950 C 12.381,11.530 11.377,11.990 10.627,11.990 L 1.362,11.990 C 1.056,11.990 0.622,11.896 0.622,11.513 C 0.622,11.308 0.750,11.104 0.885,10.950 L 3.747,7.579 C 4.241,6.999 5.245,6.540 5.995,6.540 L 15.259,6.540 C 15.566,6.540 16.000,6.634 16.000,7.016 C 16.000,7.221 15.872,7.426 15.736,7.579 Z M 13.079,5.450 L 5.995,5.450 C 4.931,5.450 3.610,6.054 2.921,6.872 L 0.051,10.244 L 0.009,10.295 C 0.009,10.227 0.000,10.150 0.000,10.082 L 0.000,1.907 C 0.000,0.860 0.860,0.000 1.907,0.000 L 4.632,0.000 C 5.679,0.000 6.540,0.860 6.540,1.907 L 6.540,2.180 L 11.172,2.180 C 12.219,2.180 13.079,3.040 13.079,4.087 L 13.079,5.450 Z"/>
    </Viewbox>
```

Now, you'll notice on the icon above, I have a `Fill="#ff2d66b0"`

Is there a way I can get to this attribute directly in my XAML code? Reason being, I would obviously like to control the fill color for different designs. I can obviously make an `iconFolderOpenBlue`, `iconFolderOpenRed`, and so on, but that does not seem very efficient.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `Path.Fill` property by binding it to the `ContentControl`'s `Background` property for example, by using a `RelativeSource`  binding :

```
  <Viewbox x:Key="iconFolderOpen" x:Shared="False" Stretch="Uniform">
        <Path Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}},Path=Background}"  Data="F1 M 15.736,7.579 L 12.875,10.950 C 12.381,11.530 11.377,11.990 10.627,11.990 L 1.362,11.990 C 1.056,11.990 0.622,11.896 0.622,11.513 C 0.622,11.308 0.750,11.104 0.885,10.950 L 3.747,7.579 C 4.241,6.999 5.245,6.540 5.995,6.540 L 15.259,6.540 C 15.566,6.540 16.000,6.634 16.000,7.016 C 16.000,7.221 15.872,7.426 15.736,7.579 Z M 13.079,5.450 L 5.995,5.450 C 4.931,5.450 3.610,6.054 2.921,6.872 L 0.051,10.244 L 0.009,10.295 C 0.009,10.227 0.000,10.150 0.000,10.082 L 0.000,1.907 C 0.000,0.860 0.860,0.000 1.907,0.000 L 4.632,0.000 C 5.679,0.000 6.540,0.860 6.540,1.907 L 6.540,2.180 L 11.172,2.180 C 12.219,2.180 13.079,3.040 13.079,4.087 L 13.079,5.450 Z"/>
    </Viewbox>
```

and to change the `fill` just set the `ContentControl` `Background`

```
 <Button Name="btnName" Width="194" TabIndex="3514" Click="btnName_Click" Margin="5,10,0,10"  >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ContentControl Width="16" Background="Red" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="{StaticResource iconFolderOpen}" />
            <Label>Click Me</Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Thanks SamTheDev, perfect! Works for me